# Laravel 5.1 throws ReflectionException after upgrade from 5.0

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have recently upgraded Laravel to version 5.1 from 5.0, but whenever I send an API response to the server, it throws an exception like the following:

```
ReflectionException in RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php line 57: Class App\Http\Requests\User\GetRequest does not exist
```

Before upgrading everything was working fine.

This is the `autoload` section of my *composer.json* file:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Bloom\\" : "library/Bloom"
    }
}
```

Could it be that I did something went wrong during the upgrade procedure?

This is how the `GetRequest` class is declared:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Requests\User;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Requests\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

/**
 * Class GetRequest
 * @package App\Http\Requests\User
 */
class GetRequest extends Request {
```

**Update**: I just reinstalled Laravel 5.1 and moved all the old files to the new installation but I still receive the same error.

**Update 2**: After running `php composer dump-autoload -o` I can notice that the file *vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php* contains the class that Laravel is unable to find:

```
 'App\\Http\\Requests\\User\\GetRequest' => $baseDir . '/app/Http/Requests/User/GetRequest.php',
```

**Update 3**: I tried also to create a new request using

```
php artisan make:request TestRequest
```

and then using the TestRequest in the UserController.php

```
/**
 * @param GetRequest $request
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function get(TestRequest $request)
{
    if(!$this->userRepository->getUser()) return $this->respondOK('User not found.');

    $user = $this->userRepository->getUser();

    return $this->respondOK('', (new UserTransformer())->transform($user->toArray()));
}
```

but I still receive the same error.

Comment: Tried `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you do all the steps in http://laravel.com/docs/master/upgrade#upgrade-5.1.0 ?

Comment: I did. I'll try to follow them step by step and see if I made any mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found the solution.

I noticed that if in `GetRequest` class I swap `use App\Http\Requests\Request;` with `use Request;` then the `GetRequest` class is found and the *ReflectionException* is not thrown anymore.

So the problem is not in the `App\Http\Requests\User\GetRequest` class but in the abstract class `App\Http\Requests\Request`.

After looking at the `App\Http\Requests\Request` class, to which I made changes, I decided to replace it with the dist version from Laravel and then I reapplied my changes.

**Long story short**: The problem was in  `App\Http\Requests\Request` because I made changes to it and something changed with the update to Laravel 5.1.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem. Currently I found the solution as specify "use" in the controller that used new request class.
Set "use" in controller for right path to the request files:

```
use App\Http\Requests\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\YOUR_NEW_REQUEST_CLASSRequest;
```